# g++ Static analysis: false positive with -fanalyzer?

Tags: g++, static-analysis

Running this [very little snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/8399T1511), to show a problem I have with a much larger code:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    auto res = make_unique<int>();

    auto ptr = res.get();

    if (ptr) {
        *ptr = 5;
        cout << *ptr << endl;
    }




  return 0;
}
```

with the -fanalyzer switch, I get a warning

```
warning: dereference of possibly-NULL 'operator new(4)' [CWE-690] [-Wanalyzer-possible-null-dereference]
```

But clearly I made all I could do to avoid this warning, but it is buried in the STL, which returns a unique_ptr with no validity control..

I understand the word "possibly" though..

Anyway to correct this on my side?

#### Update:

I made a mistake in the first go, now corrected

#### Update 2:

Even that code is refused

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    auto i = new int(3);

    if (!i) {

        return 1;
    }

  unique_ptr<int> res(i);
  auto ptr = res.get();

  if (!ptr) {
    return 1;
  }
  *ptr = 5;
  cout << *ptr << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Please, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/z7nG3PW9h)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: yes, a mistake of mine. Corrected but the problem remains

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug to me. It is not present in gcc-10. In the first example, it goes away if you explicitly pass `0` to `make_unique`.

Comment: Ok exactly what I though. Thank you

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. +1 by the way, thanks again, I will fill a bug report.

Comment: Problem is already reported : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94355 . `new` may return null pointer if an overload of `new` exists is declared noexcept.

Answer (score 0):

As for now (gcc-12), the analyzer is not recommended for C++ code although work is underway to support it.

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/12/state-static-analysis-gcc-12-compiler#toward_support_for_c__